# udev rule triggers error "Read-only file system"

Tags: ubuntu, udev

I created an udev rule that launches a shell script that creates a directory /media/my-disk when some specific USB HD is connected. It has been working many months, but after a reboot (probably some packages were updated) it shows the following message (in syslog) everytime I plug the drive in:

`mkdir: cannot create directory '/media/my-disk': Read-only file system`

I have added the following lines to the script:

```
whoami
mount
```

And the result is:

```
root

usb-mount.sh: /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt on / type btrfs (ro,relatime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=257,subvol=/@)
```

So it seems udev is seeing the root filesystem as readonly, but if I execute `sudo mount` manually it shows it mounted as read/write:

```
/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt on / type btrfs (rw,relatime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=257,subvol=/@)
```

I've searched on the Internet and I've found the same exact problem but without a solution:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=210243

Restarting the udev service solves the problem until the next reboot.

What can I check solve it permanently?

NOTE: I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

1. The `systemd-udevd` process was started before the root filesystem was remounted read-write, and see it read-only.
2. The `systemd-udevd` process is constraint by some security mechanism, AppArmor in the Ubuntu case.

But the fact that it works when you restart `udev` manually strongly indicates the first possibility. I would try to remount the rootfs read-write in `usb-mount.sh`, with a command like:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```